# C# Dapper - What is wrong with this MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I created a database table using this line:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
uniquename VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY, creationtime TIMESTAMP, 
updatedtime TIMESTAMP);
```

Here is my dapper-dot-net INSERT OR UPDATE command:

```
const string uniquename = "25975B8F882E7B1DD99116B71C5A8D04";

// Has format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
string mysqlTimeStampString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToMysqlTimeStampString();

dbConn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO mytable (uniquename, creationtime, 
updatedtime) VALUES (@uniquename, @creationtime, @updatedtime) ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE updatedtime=@updatedtime;", new { uniquename=uniquename, 
creationtime = mysqlTimeStampString, updatedtime = mysqlTimeStampString });
```

After the first time I ran it, I `select * from mytable \G` and I got this result:

```
id: 1
uniquename: 25975B8F882E7B1DD99116B71C5A8D04
creationtime: 2016-01-25 00:06:55
updatedtime: 2016-01-25 00:06:55
```

So far everything looks good, but when I run the same INSERT OR UPDATE a few minutes later, I get this result:

```
id: 1
uniquename: 25975B8F882E7B1DD99116B71C5A8D04
creationtime: 2016-01-24 19:10:00
updatedtime: 2016-01-25 00:10:00
```

This is puzzling for the following reasons:

1. On duplicate, only the `updatedtime` field is supposed to be updated, but both the `creationtime` and `duplicatetime` fields are being updated. Why are both fields being updated?
2. The `mysqlTimeStampString` string is passed into the INSERT OR UPDATE command twice. Literally one string passed in twice, so there is absolutely no possibility that `creationtime` is local time while `updatedtime` is UTC. How on earth is it possible, during the duplicate update, that the `creationtime` is being converted to local time (UTC -5:00) while the `updatedtime` is set to UTC?

The best I can figure, this must be a dapper bug, mysql bug, or both, or my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I don't understand how the command can work at all. You're trying to match on duplicate IDs, but you're not passing in an id. The fact that you're getting a match indicates to me that something else is updating the data. As far as I can see, that code will *always* insert.

Comment: Also, you should be able to simply pass a DateTime into dapper, without passing a string. You might also try `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updatedtime = VALUES(updatedtime)`

Comment: if the links to the .cs files listed on the tag wiki page weren't broken, I'd download and breakpoint it for you.

Comment: But I could see this totally happening. It's an orm. It's an IODKU. All day long data developers chase around these anomalies. Geez, why did this timestamp come back wrong? Oh, `from_unixtime` with TZ diff.

Comment: @Rob The mysql [insert on duplicate page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says "If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the create table statement `creationtime` timestamp firld is defined first. According to mysql's documentation on auto initialising [timestamp fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> By default, the first TIMESTAMP column has both DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if neither is
>   specified explicitly.

2. Since it is mysql and not the c# code that updates `creationtime` field, its value is set according to mysql server's clock and timezone setting.

The documentation I linked in the 1st point also describes how to override these settings so that `creationtime` field does not get updated by mysql. The solutions are described right below the quoted paragraph.

Comment: Yes, that solved it, thank you! To prevent the TIMESTAMP fields from auto-updating, I need to create the table as follows: `CREATE TABLE mytable(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, uniquename VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY, creationtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0, updatedtime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0);`